# The method getKeyCode() is undefined for the type KeyEvent

Tags: java, jtextfield, keylistener, keyevent

I am trying to add a keyListener to my JTextField. From what i see every one is using getKeyCode() method for the KeyEvent. I keep getting the error in Eclipse that

> The method getKeyCode() is undefined for the type KeyEvent*

What did I do Wrong?...

Here is my code:

```
TF_Message.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() 
{
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
        {
            ACTION_B_SEND();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @thegauravmahawar is there. Look at last line.

Comment: @thegauravmahawar the closing bracket is not missing. It's in the last line before the final semicolon

Comment: Is the KeyEvent - java.awt.event.KeyEvent?

Comment: I tried your code with an little exmaple and everything works fine for me. Is it possible that your not importing the right KeyEvent, like @BOND said?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a KeyListener.

A `JTextField` is designed to be used with an `ActionListener`:

```
textField.addActionListener(...);
```

The ActionListener will be invoked when the Enter key is pressed.

```
ACTION_B_SEND();
```

Also, methods should NOT start with an upper case character. Learn by example from the Java API and don't make up your own conventions.

Same with variable names. They should NOT start with an upper case character.